# Why does Reynardine take the form of a wolf instead a fox?

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

Reynard's natural form is a big, red fox - we can see it clearly when he and Antimony are in ether:
[image]

After possessing the wolf-toy, he can change shape however as he wishes, saying "body is just a plaything of a mind"
[image]

Yet almost always he assumes the form of a wolf - initially I thought its mostly because he is in a toy-wolfs body, but since the Gunnerkrig Court is so full of hidden symbolism, doesn't it have a deeper meaning? Is it because he is trying to protect Annie?

[image]

Comment: An enormous wolf is more scary than an enormous fox, perhaps that's the point.

Comment: Yes, indeed but usually Reynard looks like a tame white dog rather than a big scary wolf. And since one of his form is more humanoid, he could as well look like a big scary demon... or dragon, or whatever. But in general, I agree with you @Valorum, but maybe there is another  explanations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since @jwodder didn't post the answer, I'll do it myself:

Reynardine is a wolf (well, in a shape of a wolf), not only because he is trapped in Antimony's toy-wolf (or simply because he can look this way more intimidating) but because in alchemy (and Gunnerkrigg Court is often inspired by alchemy) metal antimony is called "a grey wolf":

> **In the work with minerals, the metal antimony was referred to as the Grey Wolf**, because when molten it greedily swallowed up many other metals, such as copper, tin and lead, by forming alloys. In this sense it behaved like metallic mercury which also readily amalgamated with metals. The Grey Wolf of antimony became especially important in early 17th century alchemy - its curative properties being popularised through the writings published under the name of Basil Valentine. ([Source](http://www.alchemywebsite.com/animal.html))

Comment: Renard, Reynard, and Reynardine are all literal variations on the word "fox" in France, where he is from.  Is there any doubt that he is a fox spirit / demi-god?  Maybe I'm reading too much into "is a wolf", and you meant "takes the form of a wolf"

Comment: @Cireo Reynard was a magical, intelligent **fox**. Once, he has fallen in love in Surma (Antimony's mother), he has asked Coyote to be able to posses any creature (he was hoping to posses a human body so Surma could be with him). After his imprisonment by the Court, he has escaped by possessing Antimony's plush toy-wolf - he can't anymore posses another living creature, but **he can change shape**. My question was then "why does he continue to **look like a wolf***instead as a fox". So by "is a wolf" I've meant "Is in a wolf's shape"

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarity, wasn't attempting to impugn your lovely answer =)